# Reason for NullPointerException if setContentView() is not used

Tags: android, layout-inflater, setcontentview

I know that we need to place `setContentView()` in the `onCreate()` method before initializing any view otherwise it will throw a null pointer exception.
But what is the reason for it?Is the `setContentView()` similar to the `inflate()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> before initializing any view

I do not know for certain what you mean by "initializing any view". Given the rest of your question, I am going to interpret this as meaning "call `findViewById()` on the activity".

You need to call `setContentView()` before calling `findViewById()`, because otherwise there are no widgets to find.

> Is the setContentView() similar to the inflate() method?

`setContentView()` will use a `LayoutInflater` and `inflate()` under the covers, if you pass a layout resource ID into the `setContentView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If no content View is set then from where you will reference the views like EditText,TextView,ListVIew and all other components which you have used in your layout.

It is like you have items in your bucket and its cover is locked for safety, you came in house without bucket and forgot it in the car and your mom asked you to put items 1 by 1 on Kitchen counter , but you don't have bucket?? so first you will get bucket then you will take out items from it.

Simply first you have to have a **Container** in your activity so that you can reference its **items** by using their **ID** which are assigned in layout xml.
Hope it is clear to you.!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Agree with @CommonsWare. In some details, let say if you have some views defined in your xml layout file and you want to use those views in you activity, so in this case you have to call `setContentView(<R.layout.xml_layout_name>)` and after that to inititlalize view using `findViewById(R.id.<view_name>)` with resource name as your xml layout defined name.

> Ok but why we have to call `setContentView()` ?

So when you call `setContentView()` application activity means android nutshell will render views and prepare view hierarchy for your activity from layout file. Just remember you have defined views in layout using xml file and you are using those views in Java code, so for that all works to preparing views for you will do `setContentView()` that's why when you call `findViewById()` without `setContentView()` then your application can not find views from view hierarchy and it will throw `NullPointerException`.

> `setContentView()` similar to the `inflate()` method ?

Some how, because both are doing the same thing, rendering views from given xml layout files but scope of works is different. setContentView() provides views throughout your activity scope while inflate() will only gives you a view from the layout file, that's why whenever you have used inflate() you have to always use reference of return `view` to call `findViewById()` like

pseudo code only for your understanding,

```
View view = infalter.inflate(<R.layout.<file_name>>);
TextView mextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

And yes, `setContentView()` uses the same `inflater.inflate()` method too.

And when `setContentView()` and `inflate()` not required?

If you are creating dynamically views, in java code then you don't have to required call either `setContentView()` or `inflate()`.

**Note:** In old android version when you create a dynamically views using java code and you pass it to some ListView's header or footer it won't work. For this views must be inflated before set to the ListView.